# Browser get request 404'd but works with Postman app

Tags: javascript, html, browser, axios, postman

Title says it all, trying to retrieve some data with the openweather api.

It works fine on Postman, however when using vanillaJS in a local environment I get an error message in console

```
ERROR: GET http://127.0.0.1:5500/api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/forecast?id=2193733&appid=MYAPIKEY 404 (Not Found)
```

My code looks like this

```
axios.get(`api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/forecast?id=2193733&appid=MYAPIKEY`)
         .then(response => {
             console.log(response);
         })
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Missing protocol in url. Look where request is going in your error. It is going to your server not the api

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are getting the request Sent on top of your app that's running axios.

Try `axios.get('http://api.openwheather...')` and it should work

Comment: Thanks mate, I also have to note that this also solves the problem for ip addresses. I was doind xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx/something and adding http:// in front of the ip solved the problem!